# Calculating if Leaflet route is going through turf.js buffered area

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to use `turf.js` in my Leaflet project. The idea is that I add points on the map using turf with each of the points having a buffered area. Afterwards, once a given route is calculated, I would like to know how much of the route is passing through a buffered area. I thought maybe `intersectLine()` could be the solution, but I can't really figure out how to do it.

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid', {
    scrollWheelZoom: true,
    doubleClickZoom: false
  }).setView([49.7912234205456, 9.951213004702362], 13);

var base = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(mymap);

start_point = L.latLng(49.802445400756845, 9.934930780060224)
end_point = L.latLng(49.79323509307367, 9.93476886855662)

  function routingFunction(urlRouting) {
    var control = L.Routing.control({
      waypoints: [
        start_point,end_point 
      ],
      router: new L.Routing.OSRMv1({
        serviceUrl: urlRouting
      }),
      showAlternatives: true,
    });
    return control
  }

var testpoint = turf.point([9.9354, 49.799]);
var buffered = turf.buffer(testpoint, 50, {units: 'meters'});
buffer = L.geoJSON(buffered);
buffer.addTo(mymap);
```

So let's say we calculate the route from `N49.8002, E9.9356` to `N49.797, E9.9365`.

[image: example]

I would like to calculate how much of the route is going through the buffered area. Is there a neat way to do it? I am looking forward to ideas or experiences with similar problems.

I tried the following:

```
waypoints_route = turf.polygon(L.polyline(control._routes[0].coordinates));
var intersection = turf.intersect(buffered, waypoints_route) 
console.log(intersection)
```

But this leads to an error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: n.forEach is not a function
```

Comment: Fetch the route waypoints, assume they're a polyline, then use TurfJS's `intersect`.

Comment: @IvanSanchez great idea! I updated the question, since I got some error message. Maybe you know how to fix it?