# Input geometry is not a valid Polygon in turf.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet, turfjs

I try to use `turf.js` and its function `intersect` in my Leaflet project. My original question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68354131/calculating-if-leaflet-route-is-going-through-turf-js-buffered-area?noredirect=1#comment120805465_68354131). The problem is I cannot get a proper polygon in order to call it. The idea is to get the waypoints of the calculated route make a polgyon out of them and check where they intersect with a given buffered area.

```
    var testpoint = turf.point([9.9354, 49.799]);
    var buffered = turf.buffer(testpoint, 50, {units: 'meters'});
    
    var array = []
    control._routes[0]['coordinates'].forEach(function(e){

      array.push([e['lat'],e['lng']])
      
    });

    var test = turf.polygon(L.polygon([[array]]))
    var intersection = turf.lineIntersect(buffered, test)
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Input geometry is not a valid Polygon or MultiPolygon
```

Here I have to point out that, when using `line.intersect(buffered,buffered)` it is working correctly, therefore I am assuming that the `buffered` variable is correct.
When it comes down to the `test` variable, I have tried with no `[]`, one pair and double pair. But they all result in the same problem. I also tried to pass the array to `turf.polygon` but it couldn`t be done.

Answer (score 0):

One of the GeoJSON objects you're passing isn't formatted correctly.  Try logging the objects and then checking what exactly is wrong with something like https://geojsonlint.com/

E.g.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(buffered), JSON.stringify(test));
```